# easy_install lxml difficulties on os x 10.5

Tags: python, macos, installation, lxml, easy-install

I am trying to install lxml on my computer but am having difficulties. Can anyone help? I have provided the terminal output I am getting when I try to execute 'easy_install lxml'. I am running Mac OS X 10.5 and Python version 2.7.2. Thanks!:

```
Macintosh-8:~ momdad$ easy_install lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Reading http://codespeak.net/lxml
Best match: lxml 2.3.3
Downloading http://lxml.de/files/lxml-2.3.3.tgz
Processing lxml-2.3.3.tgz
Running lxml-2.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/NA/NA4jZIQeGBihRLry0Fm6v++++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-CAOPgi/lxml-2.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-SOj-c0
Building lxml version 2.3.3.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.12
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:276:31: error: libxml/schematron.h: No such file or directory
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:276:31: error: libxml/schematron.h: No such file or directory
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:2007: error: syntax error before ‘xmlSchemaSAXPlugStruct’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:2009: error: syntax error before ‘}’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:2007: error: syntax error before ‘xmlSchemaSAXPlugStruct’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:2009: error: syntax error before ‘}’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_1__dealloc__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:73868: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext__copy’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:73962: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_prepare’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74266: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_cleanup’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74324: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__handleParseResult’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75040: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75481: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75494: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_1__dealloc__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:73868: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext__copy’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:73962: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_prepare’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74266: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext_cleanup’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74324: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__handleParseResult’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75040: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75481: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75494: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_9iterparse__read_more_events’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:99050: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_9iterparse__read_more_events’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:99050: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_9XMLSchema__newSaxValidator’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133263: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133298: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext___cinit__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133349: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133358: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133367: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_1__dealloc__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133395: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133404: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133414: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_copy’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133448: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_inject_default_attributes’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133508: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133531: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_connect’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133578: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133588: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133588: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133597: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133624: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133633: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133648: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133648: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_disconnect’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133681: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133691: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133700: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_isvalid’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133729: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133749: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_9XMLSchema__newSaxValidator’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133262: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133263: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133298: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext___cinit__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133349: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133358: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133367: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_1__dealloc__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133395: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133404: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133414: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_copy’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133448: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133471: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_inject_default_attributes’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133508: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133531: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_connect’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133578: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133588: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133588: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133597: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133624: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133633: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133648: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133648: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_disconnect’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133681: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133691: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133700: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_30_ParserSchemaValidationContext_isvalid’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133729: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133749: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149004: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149005: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149030: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149031: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149039: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149040: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149150: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’ 
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149004: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149005: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149023: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149030: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149031: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149039: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149040: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:149150: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__ParserSchemaValidationContext’ 
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/NA/NA4jZIQeGBihRLry0Fm6v++++TI/-Tmp-//ccpgwsWT.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Just a guess, but from the error it looks like it can't find libxslt.  You may have it installed in a non-standard location (it's looking for it in `/usr/lib`) in which case there may be a command-line option to tell the installer where to look.  Otherwise, you may have to install libxslt in `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you the root cause just by looking at the error, but there are a couple of easy things you could try first:

- Run the installation as superuser (`sudo easy_install lxml`), if you haven't already.
- Try using pip for the install. I've had good luck using pip to install lxml on OSX 10.6 and 10.7, for what it's worth. If you don't have pip already, just do `sudo easy_install pip`. Then do `sudo pip install lxml`.

Let us know if that doesn't work.

Edit: I believe easy_install and pip both use the same package repos, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: i still get a build error, perhaps this line in particular indicates the source of the problem?

Comment: gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX -I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:276:31: error: libxml/schematron.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm, you probably have an old/mismatched version of libxml2. If you want to avoid mucking around with manual fixes, you could try the macports package for lxml. `port search lxml` to see the available versions.